# Implement a Stack with a circular singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to implement the a Stack in Java with a circular singly linked list as the underlying data structure. I placed the insert function for a circular linked list in replacement of the push function for the stack and so on. I don't have any errors but I'm having troubles displaying the stack. If anyone could point me in the right direction of how to display the stack or what's going wrong I'd really appreciate it!

Here is my stack class:

```
public class Stack {
private int maxSize; // size of stack array
private long[] stackArray;
private int top; // top of stack

private Node current = null;           // reference to current node
private int count = 0;              // # of nodes on list
private long iData;


public Stack(int s) // constructor
{
    maxSize = s; // set array size
    stackArray = new long[maxSize]; // create array
    top = -1; // no items yet
}
public void push(long j) // put item on top of stack
{
    Node n = new Node(j);
    if(isEmpty()){
        current = n;
    }
    n.next = current;
    current = n;
    count++;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public Node pop() // take item from top of stack
{
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    else if(count == 1){
        current.next = null;
        current = null;
        count--;
        return null;
    }else{
        Node temp = current;
        current = current.next;
        temp.next = null;
        temp = null;
        count--;
    }
    return current;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public Node peek(long key) // peek at top of stack
{
    Node head = current;
    while(head.iData != key){
        head = head.next;
    }
    return head;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean isEmpty() // true if stack is empty
{
    return (count == 0);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean isFull() // true if stack is full
{
    return (count == maxSize-1);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my constructor class

```
public class Node{
public long iData;          // data item (key)
public Node next;           // next node in the list

public Node(long id){        // constructor
    iData = id;             // next automatically nulls
}

public void displayNode(){
    System.out.print(iData + " ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack newlist = new Stack(3);
    newlist.push(1);
    newlist.push(2);
    newlist.push(3);
    newlist.push(4);

    newlist.pop();
    newlist.pop();

    newlist.push(4);

    newlist.pop();

    newlist.peek(1);

    newlist.push(5);

    while( !newlist.isEmpty() ) // until it’s empty,
    { // delete item from stack
        Node value = newlist.pop();
        System.out.print(value); // display it
        System.out.print(" ");
    } // end while
    System.out.println("");
}


//newlist.displayList();

}
```

Comment: This is not a circularly linked list (a circularly linked list is also not really appropriate for a stack). Also, `peek()` will give you an NPE if the element is not in the stack.

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense to do so. The two constructs have very different behaviors. Also "stack" is more of a concept than an actual concrete data structure, it can be implemented in a few ways. A circular linked list is just ... a circular linked list.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your main function you are printing value using `System.out.print` function. This displays the object's class name representation, then "@" followed by its hashcode.

Replace following lines

```
System.out.print(value); // display it
System.out.print(" ");
```

with

```
value.displayNode();
```

Second, in `pop` method, you are returning `null` when `count` is 1. It should return the last element which is present in the list. Also, in last `else if` clause, you should return `temp`. Replace your code with this.

```
public Node pop() // take item from top of stack
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    Node temp = current;
    if (count == 1) {
        current = null;
    } else {
        current = current.next;
    }
    count--;
    temp.next = null;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few notes on your implementation:

1) stackArray member seems to be a leftover from another array based stack implementation.

2) is max size really a requirement? if so, you don't enforce the stack size limitation in push(..)

3) Your push(..) method doesn't keep the list circular. You should close the loop back to the new node.

4) Adding a dummy node allows you to keep the linked list circular, regardless of the stack size. This can make your push(..) method simpler (as well as any iteration for printing purposes for example)

5) The peek() method contract is unclear. Usually you want the peek method to return the value in the top of the stack, without removing it. Also, why do you return type Node? This class should be hidden from the caller - it's an internal implementation detail, not something you want to expose in your API.

Following is an alternative implementation, that also supports toString():

```
public class Stack {
  private Node EOS; 
  private int count = 0; 

  public Stack() {
    EOS = new Node(0);
    EOS.next = EOS;
  }

  public void push(long j) {
    Node newNode = new Node(j);
    Node tmp = EOS.next;
    EOS.next = newNode;
    newNode.next = tmp;
    count++;
  }

  public Long pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    } else {
      count--;
      Node node = EOS.next;
      EOS.next = node.next;
      return node.iData;
    }
  }

  public Long peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    } else {
      Node node = EOS.next;
      return node.iData;
    }
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (count == 0);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Node p = EOS.next;
    while (p != EOS) {
      sb.append(p).append("\n");
      p = p.next;
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  private static class Node {
    public long iData; 
    public Node next; 

    public Node(long id) { 
      iData = id; 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "<" + iData + ">";
    }
  }
}
```